# How can I pass an array to IN operator in select query in SQL Server as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, select

I have this SQL Server query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN ('4','11',"16");
```

Instead of passing a parameter `('4','11',"16")` like this, I want to create an array variable like this [4,11,16]. and I want this to send to the above query. How can I do this? I tried the below query, but it's not working.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN (['4','11',"16"]);
```

Comment: T-SQL has no concept of arrays; you would construct the string in the client or use a table-valued-parameter and `IN (SELECT ...` - Canonical reading: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN **UNNEST**(['4','11',"16"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your initial query is correct, it's unclear why you want to change it to a version that will fail on syntax...?

If you already have an array, then simply use join, or equivalent to output the comma separated list that you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; you should rather put such an answer in a comment since it doesn't provide much new information.

Comment: I agree with you, and shall do so in future.

Comment: why because  i have an integer array of customer ids. i want to pass this array to the query.

Comment: You're going to need to transform it first, so you end up with the comma separated list that you need. Unfortunately you cannot just pass the array to the query as per your example.